# How to call variable for calculate? Java Jframe

Tags: java, jframe

```
int tmp = Integer.parseInt(jtmp.getText());
int tmp2 = Integer.parseInt(jCalc.getText());
String tmp3 = jSymbol.getText()); //The symbol is *
jCalc.setText("");
jCalcKalkulator.setText(String.valueOf(tmp + tmp3 + tmp2));
```

I want make tmp * tmp2 but with call variable from a textfield. Thanks.

Comment: Take the value of `tmp3`, pass it through a `switch` statement, and based on it's value, apply the operator to the values

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] and a clear description of the problem.  Specifically, we need to see an example of the output you want and the output you're getting (if any).  Do you want `String tmp3` to represent the _expression_ (for example, `"7 * 3"`) or the _value_ of the expression (`"21"`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that this way. But you can do

```
int operand1 = Integer.parseInt(jtmp.getText());
int operand2 = Integer.parseInt(jCalc.getText());
String operator = jSymbol.getText()); 

String result = "";
if (operator.equals("*")) {
    result = String.valueOf(operand1 * operand2);
}
// todo other operators

jCalcKalkulator.setText(result);
```

Note how the code is much more readable when you choose good variables names, rather than tmp1, tmp2 and tmp3. You should also rename jtmp to operand1TextField, jCalc to operand2TextField, and jSymbol to operatorTextField.